# jquery lightbox 0.5 top margin adjust (element.style)

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I know this is simple action but I can't seem to find what to adjust the code.

I simply want the top margin of the lightbox to move closer to the top of the browers window (just a nudge up 10-20px).

Upon using deve tools i can do this on the jquery-lightbox div:

```
element.style {
top: 46.9px;
left: 0px;
}
```

Where in the code do i change that? it's not in the lightbox css so i'm assuming it's in the .js but what do i change?

thanks,
J

Comment: a fiddle would be so useful here.

Comment: The top and left of the lightbox might be positioned on the fly. Because the top and left is not applied to class level, instead it is applied on the element level. So you have do the changes in plugin file. What is the plugin you are using?

Comment: http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/